# Ajax file upload within already existing script

Tags: php, ajax, upload

I have written a script that allows me to add room names, description etc nicely. It autosaves and appends extra forms using jquery. It all works absolutely perfect apart from when i try using `<input type="file">`. I don't particularly want to use an already existing plugin as when i click save/the autosave is triggered all data in visible forms is saved or updated in the database automatically using php and mysqli and then returns each inserts id so it's important this doesnt break, and using a plugin would probably break my system as its working the way i need it to now.

Ideally i would like to achieve the relevent filename in each file input per form saved to the database like the rest of the form information does and then trigger the upload to a folder. I hope i've explained this the best i can, its a little confusing

Below is all my relevent code. If you can shed any light i will be very grateful!

Form page:

```
<body>
    <div id="formHolder">
        <div class="addItem">
            <form method="post" action="add_room.php">
                <label for="itemName[]">Item</label>
                <input type="text" name="itemName[]">
                <label for="itemCondition[]">Condition</label>
                <input type="text" name="itemCondition[]">
                <input type="file" name="itemPhoto[]">
                <input type="hidden" name="itemId[]" value="">
                <input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="<?=$_GET['room']?>">
                <div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div>
                <div class="save">Save Item</div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="addForm">Add another room</div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    function postForm(form) {
        var $this = $(form);
        var string = $this.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_room.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                var saveIcon = $this.find('.saveIcon');
                $this.find('[type=hidden]').val(data);
                saveIcon.fadeIn(750);
                saveIcon.delay(500).fadeOut(750);
                $('#message').text('The id of the inserted information is ' + data);
            }
        });
    }

    function autosave() {
        $('form').each(function() {
            postForm(this);
        });
    }
    setInterval(autosave, 10 * 1000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').on('click', '.save', function(e) {
            postForm($(this).closest('form').get(0));
        });

        $('#addForm').on('click', function(){
            $('<form method="post" action="add_room.php"><label for="itemName[]">Item</label><input type="text" name="itemName[]"><label for="itemCondition[]">Condition</label><input type="text" name="itemConition[]"><input type="file" name="itemPhoto[]"><input type="hidden" name="itemId[]" value=""><input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="<?=$_GET["room"]?>"><div class="saveIcon" style="display: none; color: green;">SAVED!</div><div class="save">Save Item</div></form>').fadeIn(500).appendTo('.addItem');
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP

    require_once('dbConfig.php');

    $item = $_POST['itemName'];
    $condition = $_POST['itemCondition'];
    $photo = $_POST['itemPhoto'];
    $id = $_POST['itemId'];
    $parentId = $_POST['itemParent'];

    foreach($item as $key => $val) {

        if(!$id[$key]) {

            if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT test (test_title, test_desc, test_parent, test_photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))
            {
                // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
                $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $val, $condition[$key], $parentId[$key], $photo[$key]);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                echo $db->insert_id;
                //echo "success";
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Insert SQL statement.";
            }

        } 
            else
        {
            if ($stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET test_title = ?, test_desc = ?, test_photo = ? WHERE test_id = ?"))
            {
                // Use an s per variable passed to the string, example - "ss", $firstname, $lastname
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $val, $photo[$key], $id[$key]);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();

                echo $id[$key];
                //echo "success";
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Update SQL statement.";
            }
        }

    }

?>
```